# Why is a local variable assigned in one method, but unassigned in a near-identical method?

Tags: c#, exception, variable-assignment, unassigned-variable

When I compile this code, I receive a compilation error saying `writer` is an unassigned local variable in `SaveArray`.  It doesn't complain about `reader` in the similar method `LoadArray`.  Why is this the case? Shouldn't they behave the same?

```
    static void SaveArray(string fileName,  string[,] arr)
    {
        StreamWriter writer;
        try
        {
            writer = new StreamWriter(fileName);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error, could not open " + fileName + " for saving");
        }
        try 
        {
            foreach (string entry in playerArray)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(entry);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Couldn't save");
        }
        writer.Close();
    }

    static void LoadArray(string fileName, string[,] arr)
    {
        StreamReader reader;

        try
        {
            reader = new StreamReader( fileName );
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error when reading file" +fileName);
            return;
        }


        try
        {
            for(int i=0; i<=arr.GetUpperBound(0); ++i)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j<=arr.GetUpperBound(1); ++j)
                {
                    arr[i, j] = reader.ReadLine();
                }
            }

        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not read from file " +fileName);
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `new StreamWriter(fileName);` throws an exception, then `s` stays unassigned.

Attempt to use it in `s.WriteLine(entry);` is an error.

And as **@DarrenYoung** commented, `LoadArray` returns from `catch`, so `x` in `x.ReadLine()` is guaranteed to be initialized.

Comment: OK, now explain why the `x` version is ok.

Comment: @LeeTaylor It's because you return out of the LoadArray method in the first catch block.

Comment: How else can I s.WriteLine the entry?

Comment: @SzymonZmudzki You can return from `catch` block in `SaveArray` (the same way as in `LoadArray`). What is the point to continue execution if `new StreamWriter` fails?

Answer (score 2):

In `LoadArray`, a caught exception causes the method to return before the reader gets used.  In `SaveArray`, it catches the exception but then continues on its merry way, even though the writer never finished being assigned.

Always remember that a caught exception immediately breaks out of normal control flow, so the current statement will not finish execution.

Answer (score 1):

Notice how you are declaring a StreamWriter object called writer but you aren't initializing it until you enter your try/catch block. What happens if the try catch fails?

```
        StreamWriter writer;
        try
        {
            writer = new StreamWriter(fileName);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error, could not open " + fileName + " for saving");
        }
        try 
        {
            foreach (string entry in playerArray)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(entry);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Couldn't save");
        }
        writer.Close();
```